# Default server name for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wanted to use Microsoft SQL Server and thereby installed a fresh copy of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012. It was an automatic installation and did not ask me for a server name. Right now, I'm stuck at the login screen and not sure what to put as the server name. 
[image: SQL Server Management Studio 2012 - Login Screen]

I happened to refer few previously posted questions and tried using ".\SQLExpress" as the Server Name, but the following error was displayed
[image]

What could be the possible Server Name ? 
PS: The system name is "CBEUG".

Answer (score 8):

SQL Management Studio is just that - the management studio tools. It is not the SQL Server itself. For that, you will need to install the SQL Server package.

If you can't see a SQL Server services in Services, it is not installed.

Comment: I assumed it to come with SQL Server Management Studio. Thanks for clarifying. Can you recommend me what SQL Server version & package to use ? (I'm using Windows 8.1 Enterprise)

Comment: SQL 2012, which ever version you have licenses for. Or Express is free.

Comment: You could use Express Edition for free, download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062). You should be aware of [limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx), but it's ok for basic tasks.

Answer (score 2):

In the Server Name field (where you type the server name) you also have a scroll box with "Browse database..." (or something like that according to the version). That's where all of your databases are so you don't have to remember their names.
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Well I was facing same issue and when i have done something like this

```
Server name : "your computer user name"\SQLExpress
```

and use your user name and password that you have given while installing the SQL studio.

it will work.

Comment: Exactly: servername\sqlexpress

Answer (score 0):

By default it takes the name of the computer
say if the computer name is B,then enter B as server's name with windows authentication